# dplyr: function of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate functions based on rows, not on columns as with `mutate()`. For example, with

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
dfx <- data.frame(
    date = rep(seq(1,5),3),
    type = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B1', 5), rep('B2', 5)),
    value = runif(n = 15, min = 0, max = 20)
    )
```

which results in the data frame

```
#    date type     value
# 1     1    A  5.310173
# 2     2    A  7.442478
# 3     3    A 11.457067
# 4     4    A 18.164156
# 5     5    A  4.033639
# 6     1   B1 17.967794
# 7     2   B1 18.893505
# 8     3   B1 13.215956
# 9     4   B1 12.582281
# 10    5   B1  1.235725
# 11    1   B2  4.119491
# 12    2   B2  3.531135
# 13    3   B2 13.740457
# 14    4   B2  7.682074
# 15    5   B2 15.396828
```

I want to calculate the differences `A-B1` and `A-B2` of the corresponding `value`s for every `date`. While

```
library(reshape2)
dfx %>%
    dcast(date~type) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(a1=A-B1, a2=A-B2)
```

works, the reshaping seems to be a bit ugly. As far as I understood the concept of tidy data, the data structure should not be adapted to the tools once it is in tidy form but the tools should just work with the tidy data format. But maybe it's just me and the reshaping is fine...

Comment: The reshaping step seems totally logical to me....

Comment: Quoting chapter and verse from the Book of Wickham: " A general rule of thumb is that it is easier to describe functional relationships between variables [...] than between rows, and it is easier
to make comparisons between groups of observations [...] than between groups of columns." vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is how to use the tidyr package here then we can replace `dcast` with `spread` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfx %>% 
    spread(type, value) %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(a1 = A-B1, a2 = A-B2)
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

  date         a1         a2
1    1 -12.657620   1.190682
2    2 -11.451027   3.911343
3    3  -1.758889  -2.283390
4    4   5.581875  10.482081
5    5   2.797913 -11.363190
```

**Note**

1) It is true, at least in this case, that once we have done `dfx %>% spread(type,value)` that the rest of the computation does not further involve tidyr.

2) If you want to avoid the long-to-wide transformation entirely it could be done like this:

```
dfx %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarize(a1 = value[type=="A"]-value[type=="B1"], 
              a2 = value[type=="A"]-value[type=="B2"])
```

or assuming the sort order shown in the question:

```
dfx %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarize(a1 = value[1]-value[2], a2 = value[1]-value[3])
```

Both these give the same answer as the the one shown in the first solution.

**Added** Two notes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Other seem to agree that the reshaping is fine so I'll stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

A non-reshaping solution is possible, but that'd have to go through `do(.)` in `dplyr` (especially if you've more groups to subtract from group `A`), as `summarise` errors if the length of output for any group exceeds 1.

```
dfx %>% group_by(date) %>% do(data.frame(ans=tail(.$value[1]-.$value, -1L)))
# Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
# Groups: date

#    date        ans
# 1     1 -12.657620
# 2     1   1.190682
# 3     2 -11.451027
# 4     2   3.911343
# 5     3  -1.758889
# 6     3  -2.283390
# 7     4   5.581875
# 8     4  10.482081
# 9     5   2.797913
# 10    5 -11.363190
```

But probably this is inefficient compared to the reshaping answers (due to `data.frame(.)` on each group).

PS: Note that in your `dcast` answer or in the other answers, there's no need to `group_by(date)` after casting.

---

To answer @Gabor's comment:

I'd do something like:

```
dfx %>% spread(type, value) %>% 
        do(data.frame(date=.$date, a1=.$A-.$B1, a2=.$A-.$B2))
```

Grouping is unnecessary and making use of it for compactness here is not a good compromise (imagine 100,000 groups or more).

Using `mutate`, we'd want to replace all `B*` columns with the respective differences, which'd only result in having to remove the `A` column. I think this is doable using `dplyr`, but I'm not proficient enough to get there.

Comment: Regarding the PS, if one did not use `group_by(date)` one would need `mutate` rather than `summarise` and so would need to remove the unwanted variables that `group_by` eliminates so dropping `group_by` would not result in a more compact solution.